# How to check in for a value in DB through jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How can i check in for a value in DB on blur event through jQuery.
I want to display a message if value exist in Data base.
I am using Asp.Net with csharp.

[image]

Comment: 1: You'll need to use AJAX and create a controller/service on your server that you query from your page that checks the DB and responds if the requested value was found. The browser cannot access the DB directly.

2: Improve your accept-rate and you will improve your chances of getting help.

Comment: take a look at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/104/Many-ways-to-communicate-with-your-database-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call C# function from your jQuery function like --
var isExist = <%=GetValueFromDB()%>;

GetValueFromDB in the codebehind should return a string result and you can check it in your jQuery. I hope this helps.

```
    public string GetValueFromDB()
    {
        if(value is there)
          return "your result"; 
        return "emptystring";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery runs on client, so you need to go to the server.
Ajax that calls a WebMethod might work for you

Answer (score -1):

Do a webmethod and then do something along

```
$('#myInput').onblur(function() 
{
  $.get('myurl.aspx', {method : 'checkValue', mvalue : $(this).val()},function(data)
      {
        //handle your response
      });
 });
```